# I need help figuring out some Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I have tried to properly wrap my head around the below but I still have big hole in my reasoning. What is ?::, and could someone explain it properly for me

```
rule_syntax = re.compile('(\\\\*)'\
    '(?:(?::([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)?()(?:#(.*?)#)?)'\
      '|(?:<([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)?(?::([a-zA-Z_]*)'\
        '(?::((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\>]+)+)?)?)?>))')
```

Comment: are there any other parts that don't make sense or just the `?::` bit

Comment: yea, I was curious why that was there myself. it's completely useless.  it makes a match group that is empty. you can safely remove it, just make sure to adjust your match group numbers if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(?:expr)` is just like normal parentheses `(expr)`, except that for purposes of retrieving groups later (backreferences, `re.sub`, or `MatchObject.group`), parenthesized groups beginning with `?:` are excluded. This can be useful if you need to capture a complex expression in parentheses to apply another operator like `*` to it, but don't want to get it mixed in with groups that you'll actually need to retrieve later.'

`?::` is simply `?:` followed by a literal `:`.

Answer (score 4):

There are two tools that you may wish to look into to help with your understanding

1. [Regexper](http://www.regexper.com/) creates a visual representation of regex, [here's yours](http://www.regexper.com/#(%5C%5C*)(%3F%3A(%3F%3A%3A(%5Ba-zA-Z_%5D%5Ba-zA-Z_0-9%5D*)%3F()(%3F%3A%23(.*%3F)%23)%3F)%7C(%3F%3A%3C(%5Ba-zA-Z_%5D%5Ba-zA-Z_0-9%5D*)%3F(%3F%3A%3A(%5Ba-zA-Z_%5D*)(%3F%3A%3A((%3F%3A%5C%5C.%7C%5B%5E%5C%5C%3E%5D%2B)%2B)%3F)%3F)%3F%3E))):
   [image]
2. [Regexpal](http://regexpal.com) is a tool that allows you to input a regex and various strings and see what matches, [here's yours with some example matches](http://regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=(%5C%5C%5C%5C*)(%3F%3A(%3F%3A%3A(%5Ba-zA-Z_%5D%5Ba-zA-Z_0-9%5D*)%3F()(%3F%3A%23(.*%3F)%23)%3F)%7C(%3F%3A%3C(%5Ba-zA-Z_%5D%5Ba-zA-Z_0-9%5D*)%3F(%3F%3A%3A(%5Ba-zA-Z_%5D*)(%3F%3A%3A((%3F%3A%5C%5C%5C%5C.%5C%5B%5E%5C%5C%5C%5C%3E%5D%2B)%2B)%3F)%3F)%3F%3E))&input=%5C%5C%3Atest%0A%5C%5C%3Atest_with_underscore%0A%5C%5C%3Atest_with_numbers_42)

Comment: the 'here's yours' link just says "trouble: mismatched paren"